# Removing Table header if no rows are present

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-redux, material-ui

I have created a bootstrap table in react to add a row on the click of a button and delete the row in a table on the click of a button. I want to make the table header invisible when no rows are present. How do I do that?

```
Here is my code:
export class KPIDetails extends Component {
  state = {
    rows: [],
    idx: []
  };
  continue = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.nextStep();
  };
  back = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.prevStep();
  };

  handleChangeRows = idx => e => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const rows = [...this.state.rows];
    rows[idx] = {
      [name]: value
    };
    this.setState({
      rows
    });
  };

  //2
  handleAddRow = () => {
    const item = {
      KPI_Before: "",
      UOM_Before: "",
      Base_Before: "",
      Target_Before: "",
      dateTime: ""
    };
    this.setState({
      rows: [...this.state.rows, item]
    });
  };

  //3
  handleRemoveRow = () => {
    this.setState({
      rows: this.state.rows.slice(0, -1)
    });
  };
  setDate = dateTime => this.setState({ dateTime });

  deleteRow = index => {
    var rows = [...this.state.rows];
    rows.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({ rows });
  };

  render() {
    const { values, handleChange } = this.props;
    const {
      values: {
        Title,
        Details,
        What,
        Why,
        How,
        Status,
        Cost,
        Benefits,
        Kpi_Before,
        Kpi_After,
        UOM_Before,
        Base_Before,
        Target_Before,
        Time,
        dateTime
      }
    } = this.props;
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <React.Fragment>
          <div className={useStyles.root}>
            <AppBar position="static">
              <Toolbar>
                <Typography
                  gutterBottom
                  align="center"
                  style={{ width: "100%", alignItems: "center" }}
                >
                  KPI Before Implementation
                </Typography>
              </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
          </div>
          <br />
          <br />
          <Grid container>
            <Grid item xs={6}>
              <TextField
                label="KPI"
                id="Kpi_Before"
                variant="outlined"
                size="small"
                placeholder="Enter the KPI"
                onChange={handleChange("Kpi_Before")}
                defaultValue={values.Kpi_Before}
                style={{ width: "80%" }}
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={6}>
              <FormControl style={{ width: "80%" }} size="small">
                <InputLabel
                  htmlFor="UOM_Before"
                  style={{
                    marginLeft: 10,
                    top: "50%",
                    transform: "translate(0,-50%"
                  }}
                >
                  UOM
                </InputLabel>
                <Select
                  labelId="UOM_Before"
                  name="name"
                  onChange={handleChange("UOM_Before")}
                  defaultValue={values.UOM_Before}
                  variant="outlined"
                  inputProps={{
                    id: "UOM_Before"
                  }}
                >
                  <MenuItem value="Nos">Nos</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value="Percentage">Percentage</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value="Metric">Metric</MenuItem>
                </Select>
              </FormControl>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
          <br />
          <br />
          <br />
          <br />

    <Grid container>
                <Grid item xs={6} direction="row" alignItems="center">
                  <table
                    className="table table-bordered table-hover"
                    id="tab_logic"
                  >
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th className="text-center"> # </th>
                        <th className="text-center"> KPI </th>
                        <th className="text-center"> UOM </th>
                        <th className="text-center"> Base </th>
                        <th className="text-center"> Target </th>
                        <th className="text-center"> Target Date </th>
                        <th className="text-center"> Delete Row </th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      {this.state.rows.map((item, idx) => (
                        <tr id="addr1" key={idx}>
                          <td>{idx}</td>
                          <td>
                            <input
                              type="text"
                              name="Kpi_Before"
                              defaultValue={Kpi_Before}
                              onChange={this.handleChangeRows(idx)}
                              className="form-control"
                            />
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <input
                              type="text"
                              name="UOM_Before"
                              defaultValue={UOM_Before}
                              onChange={this.handleChangeRows(idx)}
                              className="form-control"
                            />
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <input
                              type="text"
                              name="Base_Before"
                              defaultValue={Base_Before}
                              onChange={this.handleChangeRows(idx)}
                              className="form-control"
                            />
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <input
                              type="text"
                              name="Target_Before"
                              defaultValue={Target_Before}
                              onChange={this.handleChangeRows(idx)}
                              className="form-control"
                            />
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <input
                              type="text"
                              name="Target_Before"
                              defaultValue={dateTime}
                              onChange={this.handleChangeRows(idx)}
                              className="form-control"
                            />
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <MuiThemeProvider theme={redTheme}>
                              <Button
                                onClick={this.deleteRow.bind(this)}
                                variant="outlined"
                                index={idx}
                                color="primary"
                                size="small"
                                style={styles.button}
                              >
                                -
                              </Button>
                            </MuiThemeProvider>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      ))}
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </Grid>
              </Grid>



          <br />
          <br />
          <br />
          <br />

          <Grid
            container
            direction="row"
            justify="left"
            alignItems="left"
            style={{ marginLeft: "5%" }}
          >
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              color="primary"
              size="small"
              onClick={this.continue}
              style={{ marginLeft: "10%" }}
              style={styles.button}
            >
              Continue
            </Button>
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              color="default"
              size="small"
              style={styles.button}
              onClick={this.back}
            >
              Back
            </Button>
          </Grid>
        </React.Fragment>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: blue,
    secondary: purple
  },
  status: {
    danger: "orange"
  }
});

const styles = {
  button: {
    margin: 5,
    verticalAlign: "bottom"
  }
};

export default KPIDetails;
```

this the code for the table:
 I have used material-ui core for the project but have used a bootstrap table here

```
              <Grid container>
                <Grid item xs={6} direction="row" alignItems="center">
                  <table
                    className="table table-bordered table-hover"
                    id="tab_logic"
                  >
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th className="text-center"> # </th>
                        <th className="text-center"> KPI </th>
                        <th className="text-center"> UOM </th>
                        <th className="text-center"> Base </th>
                        <th className="text-center"> Target </th>
                        <th className="text-center"> Target Date </th>
                        <th className="text-center"> Delete Row </th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      {this.state.rows.map((item, idx) => (
                        <tr id="addr1" key={idx}>
                          <td>{idx}</td>
                          <td>
                            <input
                              type="text"
                              name="Kpi_Before"
                              defaultValue={Kpi_Before}
                              onChange={this.handleChangeRows(idx)}
                              className="form-control"
                            />
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <input
                              type="text"
                              name="UOM_Before"
                              defaultValue={UOM_Before}
                              onChange={this.handleChangeRows(idx)}
                              className="form-control"
                            />
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <input
                              type="text"
                              name="Base_Before"
                              defaultValue={Base_Before}
                              onChange={this.handleChangeRows(idx)}
                              className="form-control"
                            />
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <input
                              type="text"
                              name="Target_Before"
                              defaultValue={Target_Before}
                              onChange={this.handleChangeRows(idx)}
                              className="form-control"
                            />
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <input
                              type="text"
                              name="Target_Before"
                              defaultValue={dateTime}
                              onChange={this.handleChangeRows(idx)}
                              className="form-control"
                            />
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <MuiThemeProvider theme={redTheme}>
                              <Button
                                onClick={this.deleteRow.bind(this)}
                                variant="outlined"
                                index={idx}
                                color="primary"
                                size="small"
                                style={styles.button}
                              >
                                -
                              </Button>
                            </MuiThemeProvider>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      ))}
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
```

Comment: Perhaps `<thead {this.state.rows.length === 0 ? 'hidden' : ''}>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code. What we are doing here is checking the length of row. if row contain any element it works naturally and if it doesn't then it won't show anything.

```
    <thead>{
        this.state.row.length>0? (<tr>
                            <th className="text-center"> # </th>
                            <th className="text-center"> KPI </th>
                            <th className="text-center"> UOM </th>
                            <th className="text-center"> Base </th>
                            <th className="text-center"> Target </th>
                            <th className="text-center"> Target Date</th>
                            <th className="text-center"> Delete Row </th>
                          </tr>):null
                          }
                        </thead>
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

```
<thead {this.state.rows.length === 0 ? 'hidden' : ''}>
```